# Interstitial Ads are not showing using AdMob

Tags: java, admob, ads, interstitial

I'm trying to add interstitial adds to my program.

I created the following `AdsManager`.

```
public class AdsManager {

    private Context context;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public AdsManager (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        MobileAds.initialize(context, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(@NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void createAds (AdView adView) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public InterstitialAd loadInterstatialAd () {

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        mInterstitialAd.load(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712",
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                        Log.d("InterstitsionalAds", "Error: " + loadAdError);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        super.onAdLoaded(interstitialAd);
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdClicked() {
                                super.onAdClicked();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                                super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                                Log.d("InterstitsionalAds", "Error: " + adError);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdImpression() {
                                super.onAdImpression();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

        return mInterstitialAd;
    }

}
```

This is how I call it in my activity:

```
adsManager = new AdsManager(this);
mInterstitialAd = adsManager.loadInterstatialAd();

if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
    mInterstitialAd.show(ColoringActivity.this);
}
```

But after that nothing happens. Ads are not shown. The debugger says that `mInterstitialAd` is null.
I tried to call it in the activity itself, without the AdsManager class, but it still doesn't work.
I also use a test ad id that google recommends [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=ru) (`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`)

My Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-8673003336752212~XXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

Also I added dependencies in my Build.Gradle (Module):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
```

I would also like to add that my banner advertising works great. I do not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ad is not loaded at the moment when you trying to show it.

```
adsManager = new AdsManager(this);
mInterstitialAd = adsManager.loadInterstatialAd(); // here you starting loading the ad

if (mInterstitialAd != null) { // and right after you want to show the ad
    mInterstitialAd.show(ColoringActivity.this);
}
```

I would recommend (as well as per google documentation) to call load method at the beginning of the activity lifecycle, and call show method when some event happened in the activity (user passed the level, clicked button etc.)